# Why do pods remain in 'pending' status?

Tags: kubernetes, vitess

I am very confused about why my pods are staying in pending status.

Vitess seems have problem scheduling the vttablet pod on nodes. I built a 2-worker-node Kubernetes cluster (nodes A & B), and started vttablets on the cluster, but only two vttablets start normally, the other three is stay in pending state.

When I allow the master node to schedule pods, then the three pending vttablets all start on the master (first error, then running normally), and I create tables, two vttablet failed to execute.

When I add two new nodes (nodes C & D) to my kubernetes cluster, tear down vitess and restart vttablet, I find that the three vttablet pods still remain in pending 
 state, also if I kick off node A or node B, I get `vttablet lost`, and it will not restart on new node. I tear down vitess, and also tear down k8s cluster, rebuild it, and this time I use nodes C & D to build a 2-worker-node k8s cluster, and all vttablet now remain in pending status.

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                               READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP            NODE               NOMINATED NODE
default       etcd-global-5zh4k77slf             1/1       Running   0          46m       192.168.2.3   t-searchredis-a2   <none>
default       etcd-global-f7db9nnfq9             1/1       Running   0          45m       192.168.2.5   t-searchredis-a2   <none>
default       etcd-global-ksh5r9k45l             1/1       Running   0          45m       192.168.1.4   t-searchredis-a1   <none>
default       etcd-operator-6f44498865-t84l5     1/1       Running   0          50m       192.168.2.2   t-searchredis-a2   <none>
default       etcd-test-5g5lmcrl2x               1/1       Running   0          46m       192.168.2.4   t-searchredis-a2   <none>
default       etcd-test-g4xrkk7wgg               1/1       Running   0          45m       192.168.1.5   t-searchredis-a1   <none>
default       etcd-test-jkq4rjrwm8               1/1       Running   0          45m       192.168.2.6   t-searchredis-a2   <none>
default       vtctld-z5d46                       1/1       Running   0          44m       192.168.1.6   t-searchredis-a1   <none>
default       vttablet-100                       0/2       Pending   0          40m       <none>        <none>             <none>
default       vttablet-101                       0/2       Pending   0          40m       <none>        <none>             <none>
default       vttablet-102                       0/2       Pending   0          40m       <none>        <none>             <none>
default       vttablet-103                       0/2       Pending   0          40m       <none>        <none>             <none>
default       vttablet-104                       0/2       Pending   0          40m       <none>        <none>             <none>


apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-11-27T07:25:19Z
  labels:
    app: vitess
    component: vttablet
    keyspace: test_keyspace
    shard: "0"
    tablet: test-0000000100
  name: vttablet-100
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "22304"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/vttablet-100
  uid: 98258046-f215-11e8-b6a1-fa163e0411d1
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - bash
    - -c
    - |-
      set -e
      mkdir -p $VTDATAROOT/tmp
      chown -R vitess /vt
      su -p -s /bin/bash -c "/vt/bin/vttablet -binlog_use_v3_resharding_mode -topo_implementation etcd2 -topo_global_server_address http://etcd-global-client:2379 -topo_global_root /global -log_dir $VTDATAROOT/tmp -alsologtostderr -port 15002 -grpc_port 16002 -service_map 'grpc-queryservice,grpc-tabletmanager,grpc-updatestream' -tablet-path test-0000000100 -tablet_hostname $(hostname -i) -init_keyspace test_keyspace -init_shard 0 -init_tablet_type replica -health_check_interval 5s -mysqlctl_socket $VTDATAROOT/mysqlctl.sock -enable_semi_sync -enable_replication_reporter -orc_api_url http://orchestrator/api -orc_discover_interval 5m -restore_from_backup -backup_storage_implementation file -file_backup_storage_root '/usr/local/MySQL_DB_Backup/test'" vitess
    env:
    - name: EXTRA_MY_CNF
      value: /vt/config/mycnf/master_mysql56.cnf
    image: vitess/lite
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /debug/vars
        port: 15002
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 60
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 10
    name: vttablet
    ports:
    - containerPort: 15002
      name: web
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 16002
      name: grpc
      protocol: TCP
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 500m
        memory: 1Gi
      requests:
        cpu: 500m
        memory: 1Gi
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /dev/log
      name: syslog
    - mountPath: /vt/vtdataroot
      name: vtdataroot
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
      name: certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-7g2jb
      readOnly: true
  - command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - |-
      mkdir -p $VTDATAROOT/tmp && chown -R vitess /vt
      su -p -c "/vt/bin/mysqlctld -log_dir $VTDATAROOT/tmp -alsologtostderr -tablet_uid 100 -socket_file $VTDATAROOT/mysqlctl.sock -init_db_sql_file $VTROOT/config/init_db.sql" vitess
    env:
    - name: EXTRA_MY_CNF
      value: /vt/config/mycnf/master_mysql56.cnf
    image: vitess/lite
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: mysql
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 500m
        memory: 1Gi
      requests:
        cpu: 500m
        memory: 1Gi
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /dev/log
      name: syslog
    - mountPath: /vt/vtdataroot
      name: vtdataroot
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-7g2jb
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /dev/log
      type: ""
    name: syslog
  - emptyDir: {}
    name: vtdataroot
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
      type: ""
    name: certs
  - name: default-token-7g2jb
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-7g2jb
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2018-11-27T07:25:19Z
    message: '0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn''t tolerate,
      2 Insufficient cpu.'
    reason: Unschedulable
    status: "False"
    type: PodScheduled
  phase: Pending
  qosClass: Guaranteed
```

Answer (score 5):

As you can see down at the bottom:

```
message: '0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn''t tolerate,
  2 Insufficient cpu.'
```

Meaning that your two worker nodes are out of resources based on the limits you specified in the pod. You will need more workers, or smaller CPU requests.